# MySQL - Timezone is GMT, PHP/Server - Timezone is BST

Tags: php, mysql, centos

I've researched a lot about this topic, and all areas lead to the following suggestion:

Fix PHP, not MySQL. I should run the server, MySQL and PHP in UTC, and change the time accordingly.

However, this is not quite possible. I've got PHP and the server running in timezone 'Europe/London', and MySQL has `@@(global and session).time_zone` as `+00:00`.

I have too many pages, functions and the etc that I'd have to change in PHP, which would take an increasingly long time, to manually correct the date.

How would I sync MySQL with the system clock, so everything is ran in BST, and changes to GMT/the others accordingly with Daylight Saving Time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake of mine. Editing `etc/my.cnf` to hold the values `default-time-zone = "SYSTEM"` solved it.